# Why won't my oven heat?

Tags: gas, oven

I have a dual-oven Maytag range, model MGT8775X.  At the top, there is a short oven with a broiler burner on top, and at the bottom there is a full-sized oven.  A few days ago all three burners stopped lighting (bottom burner in both ovens and the top, broiler burner in the top).  The display indicates that the oven is heating.  The stove-top burners light without any problem so I have gas and power.

Some research suggests that a high-temperature igniter can fail, preventing the oven from lighting but it defies reason to me that all three igniters would fail at the same time.

Any thoughts what to try next to diagnose the problem?

Comment: What model is this range?

Comment: Do you see if the igniters are glowing at all? Do you smell gas when they are trying to light?

Comment: I can't see the igniter for the oven burners.  The broiler igniter glows.  I don't smell gass.

Comment: I turned the power off at the breaker and gave the controls a minute to reset then turned it back on.  No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Against all odds, all three ignitors failed at the same time.  I had someone come to diagnose and he only had one with him so I have one oven working and two more ignitors on order.

Moral of the story: never buy Maytag.  This is the third of three Maytag appliances we purchased a few years ago which has had quality issues.